# Solr - complex query

Tags: solr

In my application I have several searches like user search, discussion search, blog search and so on. Now I also need a 'global search' which should result all type of search. My problem is that any kind of search have several restrictions.

user search:

```
  q=userLastName:*searchString*^9 userFirstName:*searchString*^10&fq=documentType:4 AND marketId:(281807 1950)
```

discussion search:

```
q=userLastNameLowerBoost:*searchString*^6 userFirstNameLowerBoost:*searchString*^5 title:*searchString*&fq=(documentType:2 AND boardType:2 AND country:3028) OR (documentType:2 AND boardType:1)
```

How can I merge these queries in one query? Is that possible?

Comment: `(user_search) (discussion_search)` as simple as this

Comment: You can use copyfield to copy user search and discussion search contents to new field and run your global search on this new field.

Comment: '(user_search) (discussion_search)' --> wont work because of the filter queries? copyfield also not a good idea because some of these fields are boosted (forgot it to say)..

Comment: can you provide more details of the fields and the boost ?

Answer (score 0):

My query examples just snippets from the queries. If I would provide more details it will be beyond the scope of the discussion. Every query (user,discussiom,blog,..) have several fields and also some equal fields. All queries hace a 'fq' query which are the problem. I restrict by documentType (1=blog, 2=discussion,..) and also I must restrict by different markets.

If I merge both queries I lost results.

e.g.

```
user search result = 60 results
     discussion search results = 10 results
     merge search results = 68 result
     --> 2 lost
```

fq query:

```
(documentType:4 AND marketId:(1956 1960 ..and so on..)) OR (documentType:3 AND marketId:(1956 ..and so son..))
```